# How to find blind and buried vias in Altium

Tags: altium, via

I need to remove some blind and buried vias that someone added a long time ago. They aren't in the layer stack manager anymore, but are still on the board. The board has thousands of vias and it is very hard to find them all. Is there a way to get Altium to find them for me, so I can delete them? Maybe via a design rule or something?

Comment: I haven't used blind or buiried vias, but I expect there would be a drill file or equivalent to give their positions.  There must be something to tell the board shop where to put them.

Answer (score 1):

Find one of the vias you want to remove, left-click on it, and click on "Find Similar Objects..."

Then in the pop-up window, you can determine which vias to select based on whichever attributes make them different than the others.  Depending on how it was set up, the Layer box might be what you are after.